# R functions' aliases documentation

Tags: r, documentation

I'm working on R package.
I set aliases for some functions this way:

```
foo <- function(){
    do_something
}

foo_alias <- foo
```

I have the documentation for 'foo' function, so when typing:

```
?foo
```

I get the created documentation. Unfortunately it does not work for foo_alias. When I type:

```
?foo_alias
```

I get nothing. Is there any solution for that so the alias function inherits the documentation from foo?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should add an alias to your documentation file:

```
\name{foo}
\alias{foo}
\alias{foo_alias}
```

Or if you use `roxygen2`:

```
#' @name foo 
foo <- function()

#' @rdname foo
foo_alias <- foo
```

Comment: In `roxygen2` you can also use `@describeIn`.

Comment: The roxygen2 approach doesn't work for me. In that `foo_alias` doesn't export and can't be used. There are no errors. The function just doesn't appear when the package is loaded. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

For Roxygen2:

```
#' @rdname foo
#' @export
foo_alias <- foo
```