# Same function but with two different names in an R package using roxygen2?

Tags: r, roxygen2

I want to create two functions that are exactly the same but have different names in a roxygen2-made R package.

#### Desired outcome

To be very clear, suppose

```
first <- function(x) {
  x + 2
}
```

I would like another function `second` such that

```
identical(first, second)
# [1] TRUE
```

#### What I know so far

[A function can be given an alias](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30773843/5783745), but that doesn't mean its alias is a callable function - rather, it means that you can call `?myalias` to [display the help file for the original function](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/man.html). But `myalias` is ***not*** a callable function within the package - i.e. you can't actually use it for anything other than `?`.

From Hadley's documentation:

> An alias is another name for the topic that can be used with ?.

#### An inelegant solution

The same function under two different names is possible by brute force - i.e. by duplicating the file in which the original function is declared and simply changing its name in the duplicate code.

This is obviously tedious, violates [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself), and introduces bloat.

#### Question

Is there a better way; one that doesn't involve large scale duplication of code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use

```
#' @rdname first
#' @export
second <- first
```

#### Your example

So if `first.R` initially looked like this

```
#' A function that adds 2
#' @name first
#' @usage first(x)
#' @param x a number
#' @export

first <- function(x) {
  x + 2
}
```

Then simply include the extra lines of code like so (the last 3 lines are all that change)

```
#' A function that adds 2
#' @name first
#' @usage first(x)
#' @param x a number
#' @export

first <- function(x) {
  x + 2
}

#' @rdname first
#' @export
second <- first
```